# IDA Pro .til files backward compatibility

Tags: ida, c, calling-conventions, interoperability

I read in the IDA Pro Book that

> you may use `till.exe` to parse header files and create standalone `.til`
>   files which can be made globally available by copying them into
>   `<IDADIR>/til`.
>   This is all well and good when you happen to have access to source code that you then allow IDA (or `till.exe`) to parse.

Now I was wondering what would happen if the header file is from a library version older than the one used by the target binary (or vice versa). The closest I could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6099885/4480139) SO answer:

> If the ABI in the exported functions don't change you should be able
>   to get away with using an older DLL with a program linked against a
>   newer .lib, as long as the program isn't using a new export that are
>   in the new .lib but not in the older DLL.
>
> Things which affect the ABI (I'm not claiming this is a comprehensive
>   list):
>
> - calling convention
> - export name
> - parameter list (including types)

Does anyone have experience with using `.til` files although the version does not exactly match? In the best case, I guess, the `.til` file should work fine. But what could happen in the worst case, i.e. if any of the above mentioned three things change?

Is there any chance I can detect when the application of a slightly wrong `.til` file causes problems?